# How to sum actual row of column to previous row of another column pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sum

I have the following df:

[image]

It comes from an excel file. Actually, i want to replicate it in Python.

The `TTA` column's first value is the first value of the `Tiempo termico` column, and from the second value of the `TTA` column on, the cells are populated with the sum of the next value of the `Tiempo termico` column and previous value of `TTA`.

How can i perform such an operation in Python 3?

Thank you very much in advance and sorry if this question results confusing, i try to be as clear as i can.

**EDIT**

The previous df is my expected output. The starting point would be having the df like this:

```
Tiempo termico (ºC dia)            TTA
                  17.84          17.84
                  16.73
                  16.51
                  16.99
                  17.58
                  18.34
                  18.51
```

And from this df, obtain the first one as output.

Comment: That df is the expected output. I have this in excel as is, and i want to get the same results in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.cumsum()`:

```
df['TTA'] = df['Tiempo termico'].cumsum()
```